# How does the JVM actually cast objects and issue a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, casting, jvm, runtime

What happens under the hood when you cast an object to a specific class like `casted = (NewClass)obj;`? I'm guessing the JVM somehow checks if the actual class of `obj` is a subclass of `NewClass`, but would there be a way for an object instance to know when it is being "casted"?

Pointers to the documentation/FAQ of some JVM implementations are also welcome, as I haven't been able to find any...

EDIT as to "why an object should know when it is being casted?":

I was recently thinking about implementing a kind of Pipe that would be both an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream`. As these are classes and not interfaces, it cannot be both (as Java cannot extend multiple classes), so I was wondering if there might be a way for an object to show a different view of itself, through a somehow-interceptable casting operation, like C++ cast operators.

Not that I wanted to implement it anyway (well, I would have for testing and funny hack purpose ;)) because it would be way too dangerous and would allow for all kind of crazy abuses and misuses.

Comment: As for your edit, it would be better to just use the type system and OOP principles instead of odd Java internals. Just have a `Pipe` class (extending Object) that has a `getInputStream` and a `getOutputStream` method, each of which returns an instance of a corresponding inner class (i.e. `Pipe$PipeInputStream` and `Pipe$PipeOutputStream`, both of which access the private/protected state of `Pipe`)

Comment: @hexafraction that's how it should be handled, and how I would have implemented it anyway. But I like to try different routes and test different ways of achieving the same things, even the ugliest hacks (I love obfuscation contests ;))

Comment: If you have a working build system that can build OpenJDK and an understanding of C++, it's all there and available for you. Just add some code that invokes an `onCast` method if it exists :)

Comment: @hexafraction oh man... You just ruined the little spare time I had left! ;) I'll start by implementing `ubyte` though (sigh)... :)

Comment: `ubyte` may have more difficulty and work involved since you need to do a lot of work both at the compiler and at the JVM. However, if you do implement it, I'd appreciate seeing a copy of the patch/changeset.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The JVM has a bytecode, `checkcast`, which is used to check if a cast can be validly performed. The actual cast check semantics are described in the [JLS§5.5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.3), and the details of the `checkcast` bytecode are described in the [JVM spec§6.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.checkcast). As an example,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   Number n = Integer.valueOf(66); // Autoboxing

   incr((Integer) n);

   System.out.println(n);
}
```

produces

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: bipush        66
       2: invokestatic  #3                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       5: astore_1
       6: aload_1
       7: checkcast     #4                  // class java/lang/Integer
      10: invokestatic  #5                  // Method incr:(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
      13: getstatic     #6                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      16: aload_1
      17: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      20: return
```

Additionally, by delving into Hotspot's source code we can see two implementations of `checkcast`, one used in production and another used for simple test and early ports.

First shown is the production template-based interpreter (thanks to [apangin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3448419/apangin) for making me aware of it) which generates code that corresponds to a null check of the reference to be cast-checked, the loading of the class information, a call to a subtype check, and a possible jump to code that throws a ClassCastException:

```cpp
void TemplateTable::checkcast() {
  transition(atos, atos);
  Label done, is_null, ok_is_subtype, quicked, resolved;
  __ testptr(rax, rax); // object is in rax
  __ jcc(Assembler::zero, is_null);

  // Get cpool & tags index
  __ get_cpool_and_tags(rcx, rdx); // rcx=cpool, rdx=tags array
  __ get_unsigned_2_byte_index_at_bcp(rbx, 1); // rbx=index
  // See if bytecode has already been quicked
  __ cmpb(Address(rdx, rbx,
                  Address::times_1,
                  Array<u1>::base_offset_in_bytes()),
          JVM_CONSTANT_Class);
  __ jcc(Assembler::equal, quicked);
  __ push(atos); // save receiver for result, and for GC
  call_VM(noreg, CAST_FROM_FN_PTR(address, InterpreterRuntime::quicken_io_cc));
  // vm_result_2 has metadata result
  __ get_vm_result_2(rax, r15_thread);
  __ pop_ptr(rdx); // restore receiver
  __ jmpb(resolved);

  // Get superklass in rax and subklass in rbx
  __ bind(quicked);
  __ mov(rdx, rax); // Save object in rdx; rax needed for subtype check
  __ movptr(rax, Address(rcx, rbx,
                       Address::times_8, sizeof(ConstantPool)));

  __ bind(resolved);
  __ load_klass(rbx, rdx);

  // Generate subtype check.  Blows rcx, rdi.  Object in rdx.
  // Superklass in rax.  Subklass in rbx.
  __ gen_subtype_check(rbx, ok_is_subtype);

  // Come here on failure
  __ push_ptr(rdx);
  // object is at TOS
  __ jump(ExternalAddress(Interpreter::_throw_ClassCastException_entry));

  // Come here on success
  __ bind(ok_is_subtype);
  __ mov(rax, rdx); // Restore object in rdx

  // Collect counts on whether this check-cast sees NULLs a lot or not.
  if (ProfileInterpreter) {
    __ jmp(done);
    __ bind(is_null);
    __ profile_null_seen(rcx);
  } else {
    __ bind(is_null);   // same as 'done'
  }
  __ bind(done);
}
```

The simple non-production interpreter can show us another example at [`bytecodeInterpreter.cpp` line 2048](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/interpreter/bytecodeInterpreter.cpp#l2048). We can actually see what happens in a *sample* compliant bytecode interpreter when a `checkcast` is reached:

```cpp
  CASE(_checkcast):
      if (STACK_OBJECT(-1) != NULL) {
        VERIFY_OOP(STACK_OBJECT(-1));
        u2 index = Bytes::get_Java_u2(pc+1);
        if (ProfileInterpreter) {
          // needs Profile_checkcast QQQ
          ShouldNotReachHere();
        }
        // Constant pool may have actual klass or unresolved klass. If it is
        // unresolved we must resolve it
        if (METHOD->constants()->tag_at(index).is_unresolved_klass()) {
          CALL_VM(InterpreterRuntime::quicken_io_cc(THREAD), handle_exception);
        }
        Klass* klassOf = (Klass*) METHOD->constants()->slot_at(index).get_klass();
        Klass* objKlassOop = STACK_OBJECT(-1)->klass(); //ebx
        //
        // Check for compatibilty. This check must not GC!!
        // Seems way more expensive now that we must dispatch
        //
        if (objKlassOop != klassOf &&
            !objKlassOop->is_subtype_of(klassOf)) {
          ResourceMark rm(THREAD);
          const char* objName = objKlassOop->external_name();
          const char* klassName = klassOf->external_name();
          char* message = SharedRuntime::generate_class_cast_message(
            objName, klassName);
          VM_JAVA_ERROR(vmSymbols::java_lang_ClassCastException(), message);
        }
      } else {
        if (UncommonNullCast) {
            //              istate->method()->set_null_cast_seen();
            // [RGV] Not sure what to do here!

        }
      }
      UPDATE_PC_AND_CONTINUE(3);
```

In a nutshell, it grabs the argument off the stack, gets the Class object from the constant pool (resolving if necessary), and checks if the argument is assignable to that class. If not, it gets the names of the object's type and of the class to which the cast was attempted, constructs an exception message, and throws a ClassCastException with that message. Oddly enough, the mechanism for throwing a ClassCastException is not the same as that used for the `athrow` bytecode (using `VM_JAVA_ERROR` instead of `set_pending_exception`).

**Response to edit:** it would be better to just use the type system and OOP principles instead of odd Java internals. Just have a `Pipe` class (extending Object) that has a `getInputStream` and a `getOutputStream` method, each of which returns an instance of a corresponding inner class (i.e. `Pipe$PipeInputStream` and `Pipe$PipeOutputStream`, both of which access the private/protected state of `Pipe`)

Comment: @Matthieu Not a problem. There's a ton of cool stuff you can find in just `bytecodeInterpreter.cpp` (since it handles bytecodes, exceptions, returns, and so on)

Comment: Since you refer to `bytecodeInterpreter.cpp`, you must know that this code is **never executed** in production JVM. This is a simple draft implementation intended only for experiments and quick ports to new platforms, it is way too far from the actual implementation. The 'real' interpreter (aka template interpreter) is written in platform-specific macroassembler, its sources are at `src/cpu/<arch>/vm/templateInterpreter_<arch>.cpp` and `src/cpu/<arch>/vm/templateTable_<arch>.cpp`.

Comment: @apangin I was not aware. Thank you for clarifying; I will update the code samples and analysis shortly.

Answer (score 3):

This checking occurs twice, during compile time by the compiler and during run time by the jvm.

During compile time, the compiler sees if the elements belong to the same hierarchy,(eg: Vehicle->Car->BMW) , and it is only at runtime that the jvm sees that what the object really is.The compiler deals with references and the jvm deals with objects.

Now, during classcast exception, the elements that are casted incorrectly are in same hierarchy, so the compilation occurs successfully, BUT the jvm during runtime sees the object and identifies the incorrect cast and the exception is thrown.

Comment: is there anything called typecasting, in this scenario?? done by either compiler or jvm. (or) is it just only checking performed at both the compile and run time?? - please help with answer